# Однородные + "и даже"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, частица

Нужна ли тут запятая?

> Ты приходишь ко мне и просишь, но просишь без уважения(,) и даже не
>   называешь меня крёстным...

Answer (score 2):

Ты приходишь ко мне и просишь, но **просишь** без уважения и **даже не называешь** меня крёстным...

Запятая не ставится, это однородные сказуемые, они разделены союзом НО  на две группы. Во второй группе соединительная связь, одиночный союз И.

О частице **даже**

Связь при наличии частицы ***даже***  не чисто однородная, **а дифференцированная.** Основное (соединительное иди другое) значение при дифференцированной связи  осложняют частицы, наречия, модальные слова (даже, поэтому, хотя и, особенно и др).

Пример:
По полиграфическому исполнению периодики **мы вышли** на мировой уровень **и даже** в чём-то его **превзошли.**

**Примечание**

В некоторых случаях союз И может иметь присоединительное значение

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100#pp100

2. Если союз и имеет присоединительное значение (с помощью этого союза может присоединяться также неоднородный член предложения), то перед ним ставится запятая: [Лизавета Ивановна] разливала чай, и получала выговоры за лишний расход сахара;

Пример (наличие паузы, распространенность):

Но, несмотря на это, я каждый год **отмечаю** День Святого Валентина, **и даже**, если у меня есть время, **пеку** свои любимые миндальные пирожные в виде сердечек.

Также это предложение можно рассматривать как сложное: (я) пеку.